# Floating Figure on new Page creates missing or unavailable character(s) Error

Tags: floats, includegraphics

I have a problem using the figure environment. In my example I have three figures with pictures in them. If they are to big to fit on one site, the error

> =====Latex reported missing or unavailable character(s). =====

occurs and the thrid picture won´t appear. If I put a \newpage after the second picture everything works as intended.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}       % Standard for Linux
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}       % For German language
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{ifpdf}
\usepackage{setspace}             % For line spread
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{ulem}

% For pdflatex
\ifpdf
  % One of these two:
  \usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
  %\usepackage[pdftex]{epsfig}

  \usepackage[pdftex]{hyperref}
% For latex (dvi)
\else
  % One of these two:
  \usepackage[dvips]{graphicx}
  %\usepackage[dvips]{epsfig}

  % make the command \href from hyperref available as a 'print only'
  \newcommand{\href}[2]{#2}
\fi

\graphicspath{{pictures/}}        
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}

\geometry{a4paper,left=3cm,right=3cm}

\usepackage[style=apa, backend=biber]{biblatex}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\preto\section{\clearpage}

\begin{document}
    
\begin{figure}[ht]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth]{vector-mapping}
    \caption{Dokument als Vektor}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[ht]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.6\textwidth]{vector-mapping}
    \caption{Dokument als Vektor}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[ht]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.6\textwidth]{vector-mapping}
    \caption{Dokument als Vektor}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Does anyone know why this error appears?

Edit.: This is the picture in question:
[image: This is the picture in question]

[As Upload](https://s20.directupload.net/images/210330/zumtzni7.png)

[Log as Pastebin](https://pastebin.com/KzeKZABr)

Comment: we can't test without the pictures, but try to remove the `[ht]`.

Comment: I added the pircutre, didn´t know that i could upload images ;) Removing the [ht] does not work, unfortunately.

Comment: that is not the same as your original picture. Show your log-file.  And better don't use the tabu package, it is broken and unmaintained.

Comment: I added the log-file and the picture :)

Comment: sorry I can reproduce your problem, but you have outdated local files here /home/klaas/texmf/tex/generic/babel-german/ngerman.ldf, perhaps they are doing some nonsense.

Comment: I reinstalled texlive and tried on my second machine, both with the same result. As soon as the third image takes enough space to justify using a new site, the error occurs. Forcing the position with [H] works. I‘m going to try a windows machine tomorrow - maybe it‘s something OS specific. I’m using Linux mint normally.

Comment: Note that floats work by immediately creating and storing the image into a savebox.  None of the code is delayed.  (Except \protected@write.)